# Spring Data Elasticsearch - how to use ElasticsearchRestTemplate?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a springboot app which connects to ElasticSearch. However I would like to use `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` and I get only classNotFound.

My pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </dependency>
     <dependencies>
```

And when I try to do import

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;
```

It shows that the class does not exist. How to solve that ? Which version of Spring Elasticsearch Data to be able to use ElasticsearchRestTemplate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticsearchRestTemplate is part of [release 4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/4.x) of Spring Data ES which is still under development.

If you want to try it out (i.e. not in production) you can use the `4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` version.

Comment: Thanks a lot @val. I am new to elastic search, could you please tell me what is the difference between elasticsearchtemplate and elasticsearchresttemplate? which one to use in springboot project ?

Comment: @implosivesilence feel free to ask a new question, this one is closed already.